# .NET in js include file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, swfupload

Can I get print data in my .js files before sending them to the client?  I want to be able to print the session id into a variable to use in getting around the flash cookie bug.  Here's my code:

```
//Add our custom post-params
                var auth = "<% = If(Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName) Is Nothing, String.Empty, Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName).Value) %>";
                var ASPSESSID = "<%= Session.SessionID %>";

                this.setPostParams({
                    ASPSESSID: ASPSESSID,
                    AUTHID: auth
                });
```

That shows up exactly the same way in my js file.  I want the server to process the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include the .NET markup in the js file. You can use an [ashx](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) file to generate a dynamic script files if you really want to do it.

Why write it in the JS file? Write it to the page with [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) so the JavaScript can be cached properly. The script will still be able to access the variable in the page as long as the included script appears after the code.

Comment: I want to have a single generic js file that I can include on all my  pages which use a swfupload (to DRY my code).  That way I can just call my makeSWFUpload function and have the everything else automatic.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use immediate if. Like:

```
var auth = "<% = iif(Request...
```